# I am having trouble getting Firefox to work with Selenium (Python) as it doesn't seem to be able to find geckodriver.exe

Tags: python

For a bit of context I am on a 64-bit, Windows 10 operating system and my python version is 3.9.7.
I have Firefox version 96.0.2 installed and geckodriver 0.30.0

Every time I try and run webdriver.Firefox() I get the exception: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

I have extracted the geckodriver executable (For want of anywhere better I put the executable in the Mozilla Firefox folder in C:\Program Files and tried to add it to PATH by doing the following:

- On Windows system right click on My Computer or This PC.
- Select Properties.
- Select advanced system settings.
- Click on the Environment Variables button.
- From System Variables select Path.
- Click on Edit button.
- Click New button.
- Paste the path of GeckoDriver file.

So now at the bottom of the list in the Path environment variable I have 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox'. I have also tried 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe'. In both cases I still get the same error message about geckodriver needing to be in PATH.

Can anyone please tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Please add PATH to geckodriver as an Env Var. After this restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set executeble path inside the "Firefox" function

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('http://test.com')
```